# What is the purpose of setting an initial weight on deep learning model?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm now learning about deep learning with Keras, and to implement a deep learning model at Keras, you set the initializer to set its initial weights on.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer="random_uniform"))
```

The `kernel_initializer` can take something others, such as `random_normal`, which uses Gaussian, not uniform distribution, and `zero`, which literally sets all weights to 0.

However, I don't understand why you like to set different weights at the initializer. Specifically, what advantages does it have over setting all initial weights to 0, which sounds more natural for novices like me?

Also, should the initial weights, if needed, be **always** set a tiny value (e.g. `0.05`) to?

Comment: [On the Quality of the Initial Basin in Overspecified Neural Networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/safran16.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is greatly addressed in the [Stanford CS class CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init):

> Pitfall: all zero initialization. Lets start with what we should not do. Note that we do not know what the final value of every weight should be in the trained network, but with proper data normalization it is reasonable to assume that approximately half of the weights will be positive and half of them will be negative. A reasonable-sounding idea then might be to set all the initial weights to zero, which we expect to be the “best guess” in expectation. This turns out to be a mistake, because if every neuron in the network computes the same output, then they will also all compute the same gradients during backpropagation and undergo the exact same parameter updates. In other words, there is no source of asymmetry between neurons if their weights are initialized to be the same.

There are several weight initialization strategies; each one is best suited for a type of activation function. For instance, [Glorot's initialization](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) aims at not saturating sigmoid activations, while [He's initialization](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/He_Delving_Deep_into_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf) is meant for Rectified Linear Units (ReLUs).

Comment: I learnt from an online course as well. The teacher also mention similar things to your answer. Then I really need to known. Where I can find the weight initialization strategies for each activation functions?

Answer (score 1):

That has to do with how forward and backpropagation works. Remember that forward propagation is done by applying the activation function to the result of multiplying the activations of layer `al` by a weight matrix `Wl` plus the bias vector `bl`  for each layer of the network:

```
zl = activation(Wl * al-1 + bl)
```

where `zl` is the output of layer `l` and `a0` would be the input layer. It is easy to see from there that if the `Wl` is set to zero the output `zl` will depend only on `bl` and the activation values will be the same for every neuron in the network.

The backpropagation step of gradient descent uses `zl` calculate the gradient step and parameter updates so if every neuron in the layer has the same value those steps will also output equal values and all the neurons will learn the same parameters.

By initializing the outputs to random values in the range you'll make each neuron learn differently breaking the symmetry.